# what is the proper way to implement this JSON.parse?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm required to use the plain vanilla JSON.parse built into js. This is the xmlhttp.responseText returned from the service that I'm calling with xhr:

```
"[{\"Id\":1071,\"Title\":\"Scheduled Maintenance\",\"Summary\":\"Site will be unavailable Sunday, August 7th between 9:00AM and 10:00AM MST.\",\"Severity\":\"Informational\",\"ApplicationsImpacted\":[1068],\"IsPubliclyViewable\":true,\"IsDismissable\":true}]"
```

JSON.parse() does not convert this string into an object.  However, JSON.parse() does convert this string into an object if I write my js like this:

```
JSON.parse(JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText))
```

This seems to be a hack. Can you recommend a cleaner way to convert this string into an object?

Comment: That's not valid json. Double-parsing should NOT work. `""` is illegal json.

Comment: You should probably look at server code. It's not sending you correctly formatted JSON.

Comment: I removed the extra double quotes around the string.  That may have been a copy/paste quirk from the debug editor

Comment: Somewhere in your server logic your data is being double encoded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working fine just remove the extra quotes(") in the beginning and ending of the string. [image]

```
JSON.parse("[{\"Id\":1071,\"Title\":\"Scheduled Maintenance\",\"Summary\":\"Site will be unavailable Sunday, August 7th between 9:00AM and 10:00AM MST.\",\"Severity\":\"Informational\",\"ApplicationsImpacted\":[1068],\"IsPubliclyViewable\":true,\"IsDismissable\":true}]")
```